# Rule 10.1, Implicit conversion of complex integer expression

Tags: c, lint, misra

```
Power_s.Ch1 = ( (uint8)(((*RequestData)[0]) << 8 ) | ((*RequestData)[1]) );
```

-> It is throwing following error :

1. Violates MISRA 2004 Required Rule 12.8, out of bounds value for right hand side of shift 
    operator
2. Violates MISRA 2004 Required Rule 10.1, Implicit conversion of complex integer 
    expression

How to resolve this?

Comment: Kindly format your code.

Comment: what is the type of `RequestData`

Answer (score 0):

1.Assuming a u8 operand, left shifting more than 7bit needs a wider integer than uint8 , in your case you are shifting by 8.

2.Assuming Power_s.Ch1 as a type larger than uint8 there is an implicit conversion from unit8 to a higher integer type.

please check for integer promotion and arithmetic conversion rules.in case of shift usual unary conversions are applied separately on each operand, and the type of the result is that of the converted left operand.

Answer (score 0):

12.8 says that the right operand of a shift must be lower than the number of bits in the underlying type of the left operand. In case `RequestData` is of type `uint8_t*`, then the static analyser is telling you that it doesn't make sense to left shift an uint8_t by 8. In case `RequestData` is of some other type, the static analyser is broken.

10.1 is indeed concerned about implicit integer type promotions. Fix your code in the following manner:

```
uint8_t  u8_result  = (uint8_t)((*RequestData)[0] << SMALL_ENOUGH);
Power_s.Ch1 = (uint8_t)(u8_result | (*RequestData)[1]); // assuming Power_s.Ch1 is uint8_t.
```

You'll almost certainly have to break the expression up in several lines like above, or it will be unreadable because of the many casts.